# Does a header("location: /?param=abc"); contain a valid parameter and is compatible with all browsers?

Tags: php, http, url, header, location

Does a `header("location: /?param=abc");` contain a valid parameter and is compatible with all browsers?
Or, url to the file is a must, so it should contain a path to the file:

```
header("location: /index.php?param=abc");
```

Comment: The problem is not the file (which is irrelevant), the problem is that it's missing protocol and host, as hakre points out. So both of your alternatives are identically invalid (despite the fact that both will problably work in most browsers).

Comment: Thank you. Is header ("location: http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/?param=abc") correct then? (it doesn't contain index.php in the path, but it will actually load it)... I don't want index.php to be displayed in the address bar...

Comment: No, it isn't. URLs must start with something like `http://`, `https://`... Don't get confused by the fact that some browsers hide that from the user, it still needs to be there.

Comment: I'm sorry, I added http:// about 6 minutes ago to my comment. So, is header ("location: http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/?param=abc") correct then? (with no .php file in the URL)

Comment: Yeah, sure, just forget about "files". URLs don't care about physical files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No it is not compatbile with all all HTTP clients as HTTP requires a valid URI (absolute, not relative) for the `Location` header.

See [RFC 2616 14.30 Location](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.30) for the requirements of the specification.

Comment: The next revision of HTTP will relax that requirement (see http://trac.tools.ietf.org/wg/httpbis/trac/ticket/185).

There is no problem with using these in practice.

Comment: @JulianReschke: Well, I have not said that it does not work, but if you target all HTTP clients, you should follow the specs. The specs you refer to aren't released yet.

Comment: hakre - the revised specs reflect what's done in practice. Telling people not to use this is pointless.

Comment: @Julian Reschke: We can only test against specification, which is not pointless. I helps to re-invent the wheel actually. Also the practice you write about has change how baseURI and relativeURI are resolved to each other over the time. I don't think it's a bad idea to use an absoluteURI for interoperatbility reasons.

Comment: hakre: I'm not saying checking specs is pointless. What's pointless is insisting to check against a > 10 year old spec when you know that particular piece will be changed in the revision which is only a few months away.

Comment: Julian, the age of a spec can't hardly be the point here, right? And I appreciate your feedback which is a great addition to the answer. You can edit the answer as well if you feel it's incorrect, SO is wiki style.

Answer (score 1):

The field value is invalid per RFC 2616, but valid per the revision of RFC 2616, which will get published this year.

And yes, clients deal with it.